# como dar privilegios grant al usuario root mysql 8 para acceder desde otro host

Tags: mysql, debian

estoy intentado acceder desde fuera a mi bd pero no me deja con el usaurio root mi servidor es debian 10 y mi bd es mysql 8 he probado a darle permisos pero me da el siguiente error alguien sabe que pasa ??:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'0.0.0.0';
ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT
```

Comment: Por lo general el usuario `root` *cuenta con todos esos privilegios*, el que seguro no tiene privilegios es el usuario con el que actualmente estas trabajando; entonces considero debería ser al revés desde root crear otro user y a ese asignarle privilegios

Comment: no privilegios para otro host no tiene solo para localhost pruebalo tu mismo y veras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya puedo acceder  `UPDATE user SET host='%' WHERE user='root';` se soluciona diciendo que el usuario root puede acceder desde cualquier host

Answer (score 2):

La forma mas rápida de conocer que privilegios tiene tu usuario actual es:

Conéctate con el usuario `root` y ejecuta los siguientes comandos para verificar que permisos posee cada usuario existente en tu gestor de bases de datos:

```
USE mysql;

SELECT user, host, Grant_priv
FROM user;
```

Lo cual te debe devolver algo como lo siguiente:

```
mysql> SELECT Host, User, Grant_priv FROM user;
+-----------+------------------+------------+
| Host      | User             | Grant_priv |
+-----------+------------------+------------+
| localhost | demo             | N          |
| localhost | mysql.infoschema | N          |
| localhost | mysql.session    | N          |
| localhost | mysql.sys        | N          |
| localhost | root             | Y          |
+-----------+------------------+------------+
```

Donde como puedes verificar el usuario `demo` **no tiene privilegios asignados** y en especial **no posee el privilegio `GRANT`**, que es el necesario para el comando que tratas de ejecutar

Dado lo anterior entonces el usuario no puede asignar el permiso `GRANT` a otro usuario; para lo cual deberíamos hacer lo siguiente:

Entonces hacemos:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'demo'@'tuhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Que deacuerdo con [la documentación de MySQL 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) en el apartado **other account characteristics** indica:

> The optional WITH clause is used to enable a user to grant privileges to other users. The WITH GRANT OPTION clause gives the user the ability to give to other users any privileges the user has at the specified privilege level.

Que se pudiera traducir como:

La clausula opcional `WITH` es usada para habilitar al usuario a conceder permisos a otros usuarios. la opción `WITH GRANT OPTION` le brinda al usuario la habilidad de dar a otros usuarios cualquier privilegio que tenga el usuario en el nivel de privilegio especificado.

Ahora si el usuario en cuestión ya tiene privilegios y solo buscar agregar el `GRANT OPTIONS` entonces ejecuta el comando de este modo:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'demo'@'tuhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

De modo que tu usuario actual este en condiciones de otorgar los permisos de `GRANT` a cualquier otro usuario.

Si ejecutas de nuevo el `SELECT` de la parte superior de este modo:

```
SELECT Host, Name, Grant_priv FROM user
```

Obtendrás algo como esto:

```
mysql> SELECT Host, User, Grant_priv FROM user;
+-----------+------------------+------------+
| Host      | User             | Grant_priv |
+-----------+------------------+------------+
| localhost | demo             | Y          |
| localhost | mysql.infoschema | N          |
| localhost | mysql.session    | N          |
| localhost | mysql.sys        | N          |
| localhost | root             | Y          |
+-----------+------------------+------------+
```

Donde ya puedes notar que el permiso `GRANT` existe para el user `demo` y por lo tanto podrá otorgarlo a otros usuarios

**Referencias**

- [Otorgar `GRANT` a un usuario en MySQL 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html)
- [Lista de privilegios disponibles](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html)

Comment: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT`    si ago esto no puedo entrar a mi bd desde fuera con el usaurio root sigue sin dejarme

Comment: no entiendo si la bd la creado root

Comment: pero como se haria entoces

Comment: pero con que usuario lo ago si no tiene mas la bd es nueva

Comment: solo existe el usuario de root

Comment: bueno y alguno mas de sistema

Comment: Entonces yo vería como opción crear un usuario nuevo y luego todo lo demás que ya mencioné ;)

Comment: elel suaurio root ya tiene privilegios lo que pasa que no puede conectarse desde otro host en el campo hosts deberia poner %